# Permission error media TYPO3 6.1.0

Tags: typo3

I've got a Problem i can't upload any Media files in my Typo3 Backend.

If i choose a file in the Element browser I get a Internal Server Error 500, If i use upload i get this Error: [Link Error](http://grab.by/mlhg)

I also can't see the Thumbnails

I made the Files tyo3conf, fileadmin, typo3 and typo3temp with 777 access.

Imagemagick is also running and shows me all Test images.

Can anybody help me, I dont't know what do do.

The TYPO3 Version I use is: 6.1.0

Answer (score 0):

> I get a Internal Server Error 500

Have a look in your TYPO3 log accessible by the "log" backend module. If you can't find something there, get access to your vhost error log from the webserver. Usually, some sort of view capabilities are provided by some hoster control panels. Since it is a server error, you usually have to check the server log.

> I also can't see the Thumbnails

Check your install tool again and play with the different options there. Also check that, in `install tool > basic configuration`, you have set the default paths (maybe let the install tool search again). You may see the test images, but if they're not generated correctly or display warnings, it may not work correctly.

Generally said: It is not really programming related, so IMHO not a fit for stackoverflow.com. Ask for help on [irc.freenode.net](http://irc.freenode.net) in the `#typo3` channel, this may be more helpful.

Comment: I don't have a error on my error.log on my server. The images doesn't appear in the frontend eighter.

Comment: If you have a `500 Internal Server Error`, this usually is logged somewhere, unless the webserver is configured to not log errors. Maybe the server logs to another log? If it is another error, you need to be more precise.

Comment: I made this:  tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log that's the only error i know